# Django get Foreignkey Reverse Model Queryset

Tags: django

Querysets can be searched through upper levels but i want to reverse that. 
For example:

Instead of searching the Article Model for the Reporter. I want the Reporter Model to show me the Article Models related to it. I looked through the Docs but didn't find anything useful.

Model:

```
from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class Article(models.Model):
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter)
```

Views:

```
article = Article.objects.filter(reporter__name='somename')
```

What i want, without changing the model:

```
reporter = Reporter.objects.filter(name='somename', Article)
#show all Articles from somename
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the related name functionality.

```
articles = Reporter.objects.get(name='somename').article_set.all()
```

If you already have the reporter, this is even easier:

```
articles = my_reporter.article_set.all()
```

Comment: thanks works perfectly, exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: additionally you can find here more information https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Answer (score 0):

You have to write code like this;

```
 reporter_ids = Reporter.objects.filter(name='somename').values_list('id', flat=True)
 article = Article.objects.filter(reporter_id__in=reporter_ids)
```

Comment: Thank you but i'm trying to avoid two objects.